# How to install RMagick RubyGem on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, ruby, imagemagick, rubygems

I am getting this error while trying to install RMagick:

```
$ sudo gem install rmagick

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rmagick:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes
checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.1. Can't find Magick-config in /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/opt/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/pear/bin

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby


Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rmagick-2.13.1/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out
```

How can I install the RMagick RubyGem on Snow Leopard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might also consider taking [Homebrew](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew) for a spin.  It's been growing over the last year and is widely used as an alternative to MacPorts.

> Homebrew is a reaction to the complexity of MacPorts. It’s extremely
>   simple. Homebrew appears to be targeted more at individual packages.
>   If you want to pull in the entire world of open source software and
>   want every package, then you’re better off with MacPorts or Fink. But
>   if you’re looking for the occasional tool or utility, Homebrew is for
>   you.

Comment: Homebrew is awesome! Although, if I remember correctly, I couldn't get the Homebrew Rmagick to work when I tried it, so I had to fall back to using some script I found on the internet.

Comment: I'm not sure when you tried it last, but I'm been using Homebrew and Imagemagick with the Rmagick gem on my machine and it works great.

Comment: I think they must have fixed all the bugs because I tried it again and got it to work.

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to do it without having to use MacPorts. Thanks to [a shell script to Install ImageMagick on Snow Leopard](http://github.com/masterkain/ImageMagick-sl), I was easily able to run the script and have ImageMagick and all of its dependencies installed automatically.

First you need to download the script. If you have `git` installed...

```
cd ~/src
git clone git://github.com/masterkain/ImageMagick-sl.git
cd ImageMagick-sl
sh install_im.sh
```

At one point, it runs a command using `sudo`, so it will ask for your password. After the script has finished, ImageMagick will be installed. Now, to install the RMagick gem...

```
sudo gem install rmagick
```

That's it!

Comment: It would seem this no longer works? `... 'try_do': The complier failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.`

Comment: Have you installed the development tools yet? I think you need to install XCode first. I think the "development tools" are included when you install XCode.

Comment: I do have XCode, I think the issue was resolved. I think I had multiple installations of ImageMagick conflicting.

Comment: None of the answers work for me.  I discovered that I do have Magick-config in /opt/local/bin (probably from the port install ImageMagick but I'm not sure), but gem install does not have /opt/local/bin in its path so it's not finding it

Comment: I solved this issue now: rvm installation blew away my .bash_profile contents, which included the macports PATH setup.   After restoring /opt/local/bin to PATH, the macports ImageMagick was found by `gem install rmagick`, which then succeeded.

Answer (score 5):

OS X does not come with ImageMagick installed by default. The [ImageMagick home page](http://www.imagemagick.org/www/binary-releases.html) provides a binary installation, although they recommend using [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) instead. I would recommend using MacPorts as well, since it is a great package management system that keeps you up to date with your Unix-like software versus Apple's provided versions.

Having said that, [Rubyforge](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/install-osx.html) has some instructions on installing RMagick on OS X using MacPorts. It's slightly dated, and you might need to choose different variants for the ImageMagick installation, but it should work to get what you want.

Comment: the RubyForge worked fine for me

Comment: The MacPorts ImageMagick worked fine for me.   The only trouble was that rvm installation clobbered my .bash_profile contents, which ended up removing /opt/local/bin from my PATH.  After restoring /opt.local/bin to the PATH, the MacPorts ImageMagick worked fine for installing the rmagick gem.

Answer (score 0):

And the ImageMagick FTP call in the script needs to be updated to ftp://ftp.imagemagick.org/pub/ImageMagick/ImageMagick.tar.gz

There are two occurrences of the libpng path and two of the ImageMagick path which need to be updated.

Aaron

Answer (score 0):

You can also install ImageMagick package using [mac ports](http://www.macports.org/)

`sudo port install rb-rmagick`

and than install gem

`sudo gem install rmagick`